# Am i using Flexbox and breakpoints in a wrong way?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

Im practicing flexbox and breakpopint in material UI with reactjs and i trying to do something like this: [image]

What i what to do is set my products images and type as column and the product´s price, name, quantity, etc as row

here is my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-bassi-5844oo?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score -1):

- **option 01:**

```
                <Box sx={{display: "flex",flexDirection:"row",width:"100%"}}>
                <Box sx={{display: "flex",flexDirection:"column",width:"50%"}}>
                  <span>{product.name}</span>
                  <span>{product.quatity}</span>
                   <span>
                    {product.content?.map((item) => (
                      <li>{item}</li>
                    ))}
                  </span>
                    <span>Remove</span>
                </Box>
                <Box sx={{display: "flex",flexDirection:"column",width:"50%",alignItems:"end"}}>
                    <span>item.price</span>
                    <span>total price</span>
                </Box>
                </Box>
              </Box>
```

- **option 02:**

```
                <Box
                  sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", width: "100%" }}
                >
                  <Box
                    sx={{
                      display: "flex",
                      flexDirection: "row",
                      width: "100%"
                    }}
                  >
                    <Box
                      sx={{
                        display: "flex",
                        flexDirection: "column",
                        width: "50%",
                        alignItems: "start"
                      }}
                    >
                      <span>{product.name}</span>
                      <span>{product.quatity}</span>
                      <span>
                        {product.content?.map((item) => (
                          <li>{item}</li>
                        ))}
                      </span>
                      <span>Remove</span>
                    </Box>
                    <Box
                      sx={{
                        display: "flex",
                        flexDirection: "column",
                        width: "50%",
                        alignItems: "end"
                      }}
                    >
                      <span>item.price</span>
                      <span>total price</span>
                    </Box>
                  </Box>
                </Box>
              </Box>
```

Answer (score -2):

Not entirely sure what you're looking for. I'm assuming you want pricing information at the end of the flexbox.

You can reference [this site](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for Flexbox info

I'd say look at Justify-Content - Space-Between, with flex-row orientation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).